# render dc.js charts on brushmove instead of brushend

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to render a visualization with dc.js that responds immediately to brushmove events.

It seems that dc.js charts will only re-render when the brush stops moving ([example with dc brushend rendering](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/crime/index.html)), instead of simultaneous with the brush movement ([example with brushmove rendering](https://bl.ocks.org/alexmacy/ebe599703421757852d36bcf71174dfc)).

Is there any way to modify this behavior so that all dc charts will re-render simultaneously with the brush movement?

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, the charts do actually update as you move the brush. However, each dc.js chart by default has a **transition** set, as you can see in [the dc.js docs:](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#transitionDuration) `transitionDuration`, which controls the transition time, is set to 750 for all charts.

To change this, **set transitionDuration to 0**, which is the same as disabling transitions:

```
chart.transitionDuration(0)
```

Comment: There is also a small delay used for debouncing brush events, which can be disabled by setting `dc.constants.EVENT_DELAY` to zero. [Demo here](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/splom.html?nowait). dc.js is definitely not as fast as custom D3 code, however, so there are limits on how responsive it will get.

Comment: Thanks very much both! I ended up modifying both the `EVENT_DELAY` and `transitionDuration` settings to 0 and that has done the trick. There remains a small bit of delay due to loading the data, but it's clear that the chart(s) try to render simultaneous with the brush movement now so seems to be working. Thanks again!